# How can I implement Pinch zoom for a surface view in Android using Vitamio video player

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, pinchzoom, vitamio

I would like to implement zooming functionality in a vitamio video control. On checking vitamio code, its found that it is derived from `SurfaceView`. So I have tried changing SurfaceView to `TextureView`, but app gets crashed while starting video.

So my question is, is it possible to do a zooming using Vitamio video player, if so how can this be done (using SurfaceView or TextureView).

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we use scale gesture detector for pinch zoom in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790503/can-we-use-scale-gesture-detector-for-pinch-zoom-in-android)

Comment: use TextureView then

Comment: @pskink Is it possible with Vitamio player. See my updated question.

Comment: i have no idea what Vitamio video player is